# Объяснение смысла задачи

Tags: смысл, учебное-задание

Периметр прямоугольника равен 16 см.
Начерти тот прямоугольник, площадь которого будет наибольшей.

Comment: И-эх! По-быстрому: периметр — это сумма длин всех сторон прямоугольника. Находим сумму только двух: 8 (16 : 2). Возможные стороны (в целых числах, конечно): 1 и 7; 2 и 6; 3 и 5; 4 и 4. Соответствующие площади получаем от перемножения двух сторон: 7; 12; 15; **16**. Вывод: чертим прямоугольник со сторонами, равными 4 см (то есть квадрат).

Comment: Я не про решение, а про то как задан вопрос....

Comment: Задача написана понятно, но я бы сформулировал короче: *Начерти прямоугольник с наибольшей площадью, у которого периметр 16 см*.

Comment: Задача сформулирована безграмотно. Прямоугольника изначально нет, поэтому нельзя писать "периметр прямоугольника" (эта фраза подразумевает, что он есть). "Тот прямоугольник" тоже некорректно. Нет ещё прямоугольника, чтобы на него указывать местоимением "тот".

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Придаточное надо ближе, здесь вообще утверждали, что отрывать нельзя. И ещё очень сложная проблема есть. Образцовый вариант, как пишут в учебниках: *Начерти прямоугольник с периметром 16 см так, чтобы его площадь была наибольшей.*

Comment: @oleedd  Безотносительно к этому вопросу. "Придаточное надо ближе", "отрывать нельзя" – это совсем не соответствует действительности. Да сплошь и рядом придаточное стоит после слов, зависимых от определяемого. Даже нечего обсуждать. Ваш вариант безусловно отличный!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Тогда не надо, а желательно (отрыв ощущается, не очень хорошо). Чем дальше, тем хуже — это факт. И в задачах сначала дают данные, а потом цель, а у вас наоборот. А кстати, грамотнее получается, если переставить: *Начерти прямоугольник, у которого периметр 16 см, с наибольшей площадью.* Две проблемы этим решаются, но они ещё есть.

Comment: @oleedd  Ну какой отрыв в два слова в самом деле? Придираетесь, ничего плохого не ощущается. Вот самый короткий вариант: *Начерти прямоугольник с периметром 16 см и наибольшей площадью.*

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец *Придираетесь, ничего плохого не ощущается* — ну не для школьного учебника. А это интересный вариант. Условие и цель становятся однородными, но они-то по своей природе неоднородны.

Comment: @oleedd Цель – начертить. Всё остальное – условия.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Ладно, тогда так: вы ставите известное и неизвестное (наибольшая площадь неизвестна, её надо найти, в этом тоже цель) в один ряд, они неоднородны по своей природе.

Answer (score 1):

Комментарий: *Я не про решение, а про то, как задан вопрос.*

Очень хорошо — коротко, но понятно — задан вопрос.
**P = 2 × (a + b)**, где **a** и **b** — соседние стороны.

Прямоугольников с периметром 16 см может быть множество (например, с шагом 1 мм — 40, а с шагом 1 см — всего 4).
Нужно определить (решить каким-либо способом), какой из этого множества самый большой по площади, и начертить его.
(Самый маленький — 0,1 × 7,9 — 0,79 см².)

Comment: Плохо он задан, неправильно. Прямоугольника изначально нет, поэтому нельзя писать "периметр прямоугольника" (эта фраза означает, что он есть). Первое предложение нужно соединить со вторым. "Тот прямоугольник" тоже некорректно. Нет ещё прямоугольника, чтобы на него указывать местоимением "тот". Что-то грамотность никто не анализировал...

Answer (score 1):

Построй(те) прямоугольник наибольшей площади(с наибольшей площадью), если его периметр равен 16 см.

Слово "тот" - лишнее. начерти не говорят, потому что черчение это не совсем то, что делают по линейке (или от руки) на клетчатой бумаге. Да, не составляет труда начертить иную черту или линию, хотя *черчение* - это отдельная дисциплина с соблюдением ГОСТов и прочих правил *технического рисунка*, - но в данном случае построить, означает не только начертить, но и решить задачу. Построить = решить и начертить.

Comment: НАЧЕРТИТЬ — 1. Провести черту (черты, линии). *Начертить окружность, параллелепипед*. (http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) Что же мешает нам *начертить* прямоугольник или квадрат? ПОСТРОИТЬ — 3. *что. Матем.* Вычертить на основании расчётов геометрические фигуры, графики и т. п. *П. треугольник, пирамиду. П. ромб, куб. П. кривую зависимости*.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, довыразил) мысль и дополнил.

Comment: Вы говорите о втором значении, а здесь первое (БТС).

Comment: @oleedd если вы ко мне, то первого здесь быть не может, так как решение принято не будет из-за отсутствия расчетов и прочих выкладок. С точки зрения языка, первое допустимо, но смысла математического иметь не будет. Я не знаю как начертить квадрат максимальной площади без расчетов, может кто-то и сможет, но вряд ли это будет рядовой школьник. Задача, это не просто текст, это правильно составленный текст с указанием цели и/или способа решения. И еще я не знаю, что такое БТС) Вы придаете слишком большое значение значению, но это так не работает.

Comment: Не обязательно указывать, что надо рассчитать. Здесь говорят начертить (только о результате). А начертить можно и без расчётов: можно угадать (просто решить начертить квадрат), можно знать, что у квадрата наибольшая площадь (и это проходят в школе), можно ещё логически помыслить и прийти к этому, тоже без расчётов (мой случай). То есть без расчётов можно обойтись. Возьмём тесты. В тестах предлагают выбрать правильный вариант ответа, а не рассчитать, какой вариант правильный. Здесь так же.

Comment: Большой толковый словарь.

Comment: @oleedd понимаете, задачи решают не для того, чтобы получить ответ, это практика связанная с формированием структурного мышления. Вы можете написать "начертите мне фигуру", можете написать "нарисуйте мне фигуру" - все допустимо в рамках языковых форм, но к постановке математической задачи это отношения не имеет. Я в школе решал задачи, без выкладок, мне снижали на балл, за то что пропускал решение. Все просто. Решение - это не угадайка правильных ответов, и тоже относится к постановке проблемы. Проблема поставленная некорректно указывает на то, что составитель задачи с логикой не дружит.

Comment: @oleedd В тестах да, можно выбрать ответ, но тут явно не тест, и беда тестов как раз в том, что мозг начинает ориентироваться на уже ответы, и начинает терять навыки формирования последовательного решения. С другой стороны не всем быть начальниками, это вам не советская школа с общегосударственным стандартом образования. Для быдла можно и начерти писать - все равно не решат.

Comment: "Построить окружность" не говорят, потому что здесь нет "строительных" элементов. Как вы здесь скажете? Вполне допустимо только указывать цель, так обычно и происходит. А как уже это сделать... Да, учителя проверяют наличие решения, но задача составителей — указать цель. Предполагается, что для её осуществления необходимо решение. В задачах часто не задание, а вопрос (тоже цель). Ошибки здесь нет, "начерти" — вариант для младших школьников (как и эта задача), "построй" они просто не поймут.

Comment: Почему не говорят, когда говорят. И окружность именно строят, потому что окружность - это геометрическое место точек равноудаленных от центра. Для ее более менее точного построения необходим циркуль, ну или хотя бы нужно нарисовать центр, затем "круг", затем обозначить центр точкой О(например) и нарисовать радиус и подписать - это значит построить окружность. План причем последовательных действий, а не сначала круг, а потом центр. Это ближе к иероглифике, когда иероглиф "рисуют" не абы как а с определенной последовательностью линий. Поэтому про иероглиф говорят не чертите или рисуйте -а пишите

Comment: Не слышал. Обычно строят линиями.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142991/discussion-between--and-oleedd).

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос задан несколько коряво, но смысл его понятен. Надо максимизировать функцию

```
           s(x, y) = x y                         (1)
```

при соблюдении трёх доп. условий.  Во-первых, x должнo быть неотрицательным.  Во-вторых, y должнo быть неотрицательным. В-третьих, значение периметра должно быть фиксировано:

```
                   2 (x + y) = 16            (2а)
```

Чтобы максимизировать площадь (1) при соблюдения условия (2а), перепишем его как

```
 y = 8 - x                                      (2b)
```

и подставим результат в выражение (1) для площади:

```
        s = x y = x (8 - x)                  (3a)
```

Осталось максимизировать это выражение по x.  Для этого запишем его как

```
       s = - (x - 4)^2 + 16 .              (4)
```

Перед нами перевёрнутая вверх ногами парабола, достигающая максимума в точке  х= 4.  Из уравнения (2б) следует, что соответствующее значение у есть у = 4. Значения х и у неотрицательны.

Мы доказали, что при фиксированном значении периметра прямоугольника его площадь максимальна, когда этот прямоугольник квадрат.